# A question about a free abelian finitely generated group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

I am having a hard time solving this and it is really confusing. I don't have enough schema, which makes it problematic. Let $A$ be a finitely generated free abelian group and $B$ is a subgroup of $A.$ Assume there is a basis $\{f_1,f_2\}$ of $A$ such that $\{f_1,mnf_2\}$ is a basis of $B$, whereas $(m,n)=1.$ I have to prove there is a basis $\{g_1,g_2\}$ of $A$ such that $\{ng_1,mg_2\}$ is a basis of $B.$ How can I show that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you. That's me by the way. this website seem to be creating new accounts and I can't reach my prior accounts. I am not familiar with the technique you used but I sure will try to work with it. How can I show that {af1+mf2,bf1−nf2} is a basis? It would have to generate f1 and f2 while the coefficient are necessarily integers and not real numbers. How do I show that? I can't even put is as a command, darn. It is you, Jim, I am referring.

Comment: For example $f_1 = n(af_1+mf_2) + m(bf_1-nf_2)$.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the fact that $(m, n) = 1$.  This means there exists integers $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ such that $an + bm = 1$.  One way to think of bases is they are the columns of matrices in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$.  So you look for a way to write down a $2 \times 2$ matrix with determinant $\pm1$ using the integers $a, b, n, m$.  My first guess was
$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ m & -n \end{bmatrix}$$
and this corresponds to the basis $\{af_1 + mf_2, bf_1 - nf_2\}$.  I'll leave you to check that letting these be $g_1$ and $g_2$ works.

I wish I could say something more insightful about how to come up with this answer.  Having a limited amount of information means there are a very limited number of things you can actually try, so you just follow your nose and start trying them.